# Is it safe to make a query from android to mysql?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I'm developing an app for Android which needs data of my server. My doubt is:

Is it safe to make a query from android to mysql?

Because... I was thinking to obtain a JSON with a PHP file, but I believe this is slower method. So, now i'm trying to make a query to mysql server without any PHP file, putting the password and the user of data base in the android project.

I need to know if someone could decompile my app and see my credentials in java files.

Are there other methods?

Comment: Exposing this type of data could be dangerous of course since it will be in the clients application, and yes there is a very strenuous way to figure out your details as far as I know although it is being looked into.

Comment: Why is using PHP 'slower' ? Unless you're sending very frequent requests where every millisecond counts, I think PHP is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than "safe", there's not a native way to send data from `Android` to a `MySQL` server. The correct way is implementing a web-service that receives the query (for instance, via `HTTP POST`), then handles it, connects to the local (or remote) database and executes the requested query (and possibly returns the result if needed).

As far as security goes, this seems to be a totally different question, but in this kind of architecture it seems that a *Asymmetric encryption* algorithm is what best fits this kind of transactions, as you can hardcode/download each time you need the public key for encrypting messages and they'll be only decrypted by the server side using the private key.

Hardcoding credentials into your app is pretty much a bad idea, because if someone who has some knowledge about this subject, will try crack you app, and if your app manages some financial sensitive data, they actually will try triplify efforts.

- [How to securely share key between two remote devices?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53631/how-to-securely-share-key-between-two-remote-devices)
- [How dangerous might be publishing a public key?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54353/how-dangerous-might-be-publishing-a-public-key)

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that people can always get the db user and password from the application. This allows them to login and drop your tables in the database.

Therefore creating a small web service that will do it for you gives you more security, since you can decide what operations is allowed to perform to the database.

Comment: Since I can't comment the post of @nKn due to my bad reputation ;) I will do it here:

No mather what algorithms you will use or whatever you do. You will never be sure that the secret hidden on the application (Android App), is not obtained by an intruder. Therefore the web service to access the databae, is the best way.

Comment: I didn't say this way you'll be 100% safe, but it will make it more difficult to attackers to break the sent data. Also my answer is oriented to the web-service, anything I wrote is to be implemented in that web-service.

Comment: Sorry it was not my attention to argue against what you wrote. I would just underline that you can never be sure to hide any secret within your android apps, or iOS for that matter.

Comment: No problem. The fact that no matters whatever you do you'll never be 100% safe is true, these measures are meant just to harden as much as possible for attackers to get messages.

Answer (score 1):

Using a RESTful (in your case)PHP framework is the way to go. You can then use data from JSON or XML in your application. This way is definitely not slower. You can use this framework:

http://www.slimframework.com/

Or whatever your are using right now.